# How do I write a name from Facebook into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, api

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO friend_data (UID, Name) VALUES ($friendUID, $friendName)");
```

where $friendUID is the user ID grabbed from Facebook, and $friendName is the name of the friend grabbed from Facebook. For some reason, $friendName just won't write to MySQL. $friendUID writes fine, and so does regular text. Does anyone have an idea why, or how to get this working? Relevant code is below:

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
$friendUID = $value["id"];
$friendName = $value["name"];
echo $friendName;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO friend_data (UID, Name) VALUES ($friendUID, $friendName)");
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, you've got a SQL injection vulnerability there, and please consider switching to either using mysqli or PDO to access your database (the `mysql_` functions are obselete & using them is discouraged).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look. I'm just trying to get this working though...

Answer (score 2):

First, you should look into using MySQLi or PDO, as the PHP MySQL extension is quite old (and now deprecated in PHP5.5)
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

The issue is that you are trying to insert raw text into the SQL query, which in addition to being an injection risk, causes an invalid statement:

Desired result:

```
INSERT INTO friend_data (UID, Name) VALUES (1234, "Friend Name");
```

Actual Result:

```
INSERT INTO friend_data (UID, Name) VALUES (1234, Friend Name);
```

You need to encapsulate the name value in quotes, as well as escape the values before inserting them:

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
$friendUID = mysql_real_escape_string($value["id"]);
$friendName = mysql_real_escape_string($value["name"]);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO friend_data (UID, Name) VALUES ($friendUID, \"$friendName\")");
```

Comment: Thank you!

Speaking of PDO and MySQLi - eventually I need to write statements in a Java Applet. Do I need to modify those as well to be not injectable?

Comment: @FinalJon yes, SQL injection is an issue you need to handle regardless of language.